# Obtain web data after logging into website

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get data from a website which requires to log in a user and password. I've followed [this tutorial](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/03/08/get-data-from-website-that-requires-a-login/) and managed to log into the website, but for some reason it's not getting the table.

Here's the code:

```
Sub GetTable()

    Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
    Dim ieDoc As Object
    Dim ieTable As Object
    Dim clip As DataObject

    'create a new instance of ie
    Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

    'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
    ieApp.Visible = True

    'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
    ieApp.Navigate "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

    'fill in the login form – 
    With ieDoc.forms(0)
        .Email.Value = "email@email.com"
        .Passwd.Value = "password"
        .submit
    End With
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
    ieApp.Navigate "my-website.com"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    'get the table based on the table's id
    Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
    For i = 0 To (ieDoc.all.Length - 1)
        'Only look at tables

       If TypeName(ieDoc.all(i)) = “HTMLTable” Then
            Set ieTable = ieDoc.all(i)
            'I want to check the 3rd row (.Rows(2)) and will get an error if there
           'are less than three rows.
           If ieTable.Rows.Length > 2 Then
                'Here’s the text in the first cell of the third row that tells me
                'I have the right table
                If ieTable.Rows(0).Cells(0).innertext = "Text" Then

                    'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
                    If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
                        Set clip = New DataObject
                        clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
                        clip.PutInClipboard
                        Sheet1.Select
                        Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
                        Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'close 'er up
    ieApp.Quit
    Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: re: *'Here’s the text in the first cell of the third row'*. It looks like you are retrieving the first cell in the *first* row (the index number of both cell and row are zero-based). Try `ieTable.Rows(2).Cells(0).innertext`.

Comment: Try to change ```“HTMLTable”``` to ```"HTMLTable"```. With ```Option Explicit``` at the very beginning the code doesn't compile.

Comment: It's solved. I did as dee pointed out and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming correctly marked with `table` tag you could have used the following to get the collection of tables which you can then loop through:

```
ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
```